# When to add index in a mysql table?

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I have a doubt on create table syntax and more in deep when to create index on it.

More in deep I need to create a table by scratch loading ~1 milion record taken from a CSV.

The question is: when should I create an index on the table?
Or better:
- Do I have to prefer to use INDEX syntax on CREATE TABLE statement and then fill the table
or
- Do I have to create table, fill it and then use ALTER TABLE ADD INDEX statement?

Which is faster?

Comment: When loading a dump, it's best to NOT have indexes. Every row inserted would trigger an index update, which gets very very expensive on a large import. Best to build the index after the fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is good to create index after storing data (specially large data).

Creating index before, will burden more overhead on DBMS.